# Python google api

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api

I am trying to learn google APIs and my experience is with Python so I'm trying to use the google api python client to access some of google's services but am encountering an error building the service object.

There's no problem importing the build module from apiclient.discovery:

```
>>> from apiclient.discovery import build
>>>
```

But when it  comes time to build the service object (as done in the tutorial file that I downloaded), something crashes and I can't figure out what's going wrong!

```
>>> service = build('books','v1',developerKey=api_key)
WARNING:root:No module named locked_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 38, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 32, in <module>
ImportError: No module named locked_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 196, in build
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 242, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1036, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 911, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 520, in __init__
    self._context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>>>
```

Here's how I got to this point in case it's helpful: I began by installing the client library and all other modules that it depended on as outlined here : [Google API Python Installation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation).  I used pip (and the necessary sudo) and everything went swimmingly.  I have tried fixing my error by updating the modules with pip's --update argument but that doesn't appear to be the problem as all of them say "**Requirement already up-to-date:** {Name of Module Document Here}" so I don't believe that's the problem.

After that, I began following the tutorial.  In the tutorial, it gives the example API (that's giving me trouble) to interface with google books: [Google Books Example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#simple).  I got an API developer key from google as outlined in the beginning of the tutorial and I don't believe that's the problem as I'm not even executing the service object.

I googled the error but didn't see anyone with similar problems so I hope people here can help!

Thanks,

MLP

Answer (score 5):

same here, it seems that there is not a LockedFile in the oauth2client 2.0

```
  >>> from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile    
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named locked_file
```

also i found an open issue at github. It is a google-api-python-client error: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/179

Comment: it just got fixed in master branch

Answer (score 0):

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Looks like you have troubles with permissions.
Make `chown 'username' 'python file'`

Or `chown -R 'username' 'directory name'`

Comment: I just tried chown (on the file/dir with the api right? not the modules or anything?) but got the same error :( here are the permissions for the python file it's running from: "-rw-r--r--  1 mlp  staff  2271 Feb 18 00:54 GoogleBooksExample.py", and here are the permissions for the module it mentions immediately before in the traceback "-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel   36583 Jul 14  2015 ssl.py"

Comment: @MLP and what if run the script with admin privilegies? would it work?